# How to query users in SE data, sorting by "people reached"?

Tags: support, tags, reputation, data-explorer, people-reached

I'd like to see the number of people I reached on a specific tag compared to others in my country. Found how to [compare using the reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/194306/top-users-by-country-and-tag).

How can I compare using the number of `people reached` instead of reputation?

Comment: No easy way at the moment, a query is given on the dupe.

Comment: The question doesn't seem duplicate of `Include the “People Reached” and “Helpful Flags (count)” data in SEDE`. It's just **on held** because the `people reached` data isn't available yet.

Comment: I was a little concerned about the duplicate too. The easy answer is (which is in there too): you can't, unless you calculate it yourself. A sample is given there. I don't think this is the place to let people do all the work for you, maybe you can give it a try yourself to combine the 'per tag per country' query with the one giving in the duplicate.